# Running my Raspberry Pi and 7" screen off a battery

Tags: power-supply, battery

What I have:

- Raspberry Pi 3
- [Raspberry Pi 7” Touchscreen Display](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-78156?ICID=rpimain-related-prods)
- [Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen Display Case](https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi/cases/7-touchscreen-cases/raspberry-pi-7-touchscreen-display-case-black)

I would like to make this thing portable and would like to add a rechargeable battery.

- In the case, there is a small open space in that I could add a battery. The space is about 3 x 0.5 x 1 in (8 x 1 x 2.5 cm) so the battery would need to fit that space.
- The second part of this is that it needs to be able to provide enough power to power both the pi and the screen (and also anything on the pins or in the usb). The website for the screen says 2Amps, but I don't know how amps, volts, watts, ... work so I don't know what is needed or how this would work.
- Also, I would like it to have a long battery life. (Min 2 hr, but if I can reasonably get a much longer use out of it on a full charge, then that is even better).
- I was thinking about either using one of those power chargers used to charge your cell phone while on the go or I have seen these [Lithium ion polymer batteries](https://www.adafruit.com/categories/138) online that might work, but again, I don't know which one to get.
- Lastly, in order to keep it all within the case, I was thinking about plugging the battery into the large USB port found on the adapter board that came with the screen:

[image] but it says `PWR OUT` which makes me think it might not work. Another option I think might work is to split the wires on the battery and connect it to the pins on both the pi and the adapter board. Any ideas on if this could work or, if not, another workaround?

Either way, I would need to able to charge the battery using the micro usb port on the card or pi.

Comment: Also, I have heard that too much power could fry the pi and/or the screen.

Comment: Have you actually read the instructions on the linked website? This is actually one of the few peripherals with clear, unambiguous instructions. About the only thing it doesn't tell you is how much power it uses. You will need a power supply which supplies 2A @ 5V. Any battery will need a **minimum** capacity of 5000 mAh

Comment: Which website are you referring to?

Comment: If you check the MagPi issue #39 [MagPi issue #39](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi39.pdf), on page 44 they recommend the [Mi Power
Bank](mi.com/en/pb16000/). That'll probably give you about 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing exactly that. Using this UPS from Aliexpress (https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32783727347.html) and 6 li-po (2 series 3 paralell) I am able to obtain +15V/5A stable for my circuit (a 5A miliohmmeter; after passing thru a buck for isolated 9V/5A), as well as +5V/2,5A (via LM2576) to supply the Pi 4 + 7" HDMI display.
Such battery power gives me 8+ hours of "standby" (the Pi and the screen ON) or 2+ hours of measurements (consumption of 5V/5A for 3 seconds at a time, every 2 minutes).